# Execute stored procedure from PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I have an iOS app. There is a feature to submit a form. On form submission, I need to run a stored procedure which I wrote in pl/sql in Oracle.

I created an API in PHP to call the stored procedure to make it work. The stored procedure takes 30 minutes to execute.

I cannot optimize the stored procedure and don't want to increase the timeout of PHP.

Is there a way to call the API, trigger the stored procedure, get back to user with a message saying - "SP under execution" and get a response back once the stored procedure execution is completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with PHP - it's going to run the API and wait until it's finished.

What you need to do is spawn a new process to run the database procedure. This will allow you to return the user's request with the "I'm working" message. The trick is how to do this... Out-of-the-box PHP does not include functions for working with threads or processes. Here are a couple of options:

1. A PHP framework that includes this functionality

I don't know about other frameworks, but [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) and it's smaller, API-focused cousin [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) include queues. This is a system where you can push a job (like your database procedure) onto a queue and a background task will take over, freeing up your main process to reply to the client.

2. [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php), a PHP extension that allows working with threads.

I've never worked with this so I'll leave it to you to investigate.